# recovering lost access to RAID5

Tags: software-raid, md

I had perfectly working RAID5 and added another device.
I lost power during the RAID  recovery. Now I have no access to it - it does not exist - lsblk does no longer recognize it as RAID5 - just individual devices.

I have  build a new RAID5 and trying to add one of the devices from the old array.
I am getting "device busy" and the add is failing. I found a link solving this issue and started with this

$ sudo dmsetup table
No devices found

Hence I stopped to follow the tutorial  because it assumes some kind of "multipath" process and expects entries in the dmsetup table.

My questions are
Is my process of build new array then add devices from the old
reasonable ?
How can I gain access to the old device or restore the old array?

Comment: What RAID implementation on what software? If this is Linux md, please tag your question as such.  Please add more detail about the array configuration, and what add or replace was done to it.

Comment: You should also take a copy of all disks before proceeding. You should also not use RAID5, if data is important to you, it is too fragile for today's hard disk sizes.

Comment: we need more knowledge about the used devices and software

Comment: Kindly help me to resolve the issue by answering this question first.            How do I resolve the "device busy" ?